# MySQL query; Select data multiple wheres in join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables, and I want to get all the (post)records where the language is eng and donation amount is higher then €25.

This is the query is constructed;

```
SELECT wp_posts.* , wp_postmeta.* 
FROM wp_posts 
JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id 
WHERE (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'lang_code' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'en')
AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'donated' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) > '25' ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'donation' 
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0;
```

## Table #1 (wp_posts)

```
---------------------------------------------------
ID | name         | post_type  | post_status
---------------------------------------------------
01 | test entry 1 | donation   | publish
02 | test entry 2 | donation   | publish
03 | test entry 3 | donation   | awaiting
```

## Table #2 (wp_postmeta);

```
---------------------------------------------------
meta_id | post_id | meta_key  | meta_value
---------------------------------------------------
23      | 01      | lang_code | en
84      | 01      | donated   | 3100
25      | 02      | lang_code | en
63      | 02      | donated   | 15
```

Expected result with this demo data;

```
---------------------------------------------------
ID | name         | post_type  | post_status
---------------------------------------------------
01 | test entry 1 | donation   | publish
```

How can I get the results I need, without a subquery?

Comment: I don't see any column for the donation amount.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's a combination of meta_key `donated` and the matching data from the meta_value column. @OP: Why don't you want to use a subqueries? Does your SQL work (it looks like it might). if it works: Where is the problem with it?

Comment: @daZza Does subqueries don't make the query really slow? I also thought this query was OK. But it can't filter on on multiple meta/key => meta/values.

Comment: With that table data, what's the expected result? (Formatted text here too.)

Comment: @jarlh The result I need is from table 1 with ID = 01. That records suits the requirements

Comment: So you only want one row, from table 1. That's it? Can't you add that as formatted text, so people don't have to guess?

Comment: Yes with this demo data that is only one row. I edited the question with the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using two joins:

```
SELECT p.* , pml.*, pmd.*  -- although you probably only want the value column
FROM wp_posts p JOIN
     wp_postmeta pml
     ON p.ID = pml.post_id AND
        pml.meta_key = 'lang_code' AND
        pml.meta_value = 'en' JOIN
     wp_postmeta pmd
     ON p.ID = pmd.post_id AND
        pmd.meta_key = 'donated' AND CAST(pmd.meta_value AS SIGNED) > 25 WHERE p.post_type = 'donation' AND p.post_status = 'publish' 
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0;
```

Comment: Great, works like a charm! (I  got 1 error ON wp_posts.ID needs to be p.ID)